# Homebrew Warnings: How do I resolve these warning and correct my path on Mac 10.10.2 Yosemite?

Tags: ruby, path, warnings, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I'm fairly new to programming so I could really use your help. 
I think Yosemite upgrade has royally screwed up my path and homebrew, and was hoping you folks can help me get back on track without reseting my mac. So as I get ready to dive back into rails I ran brew doctor and got a bunch of warnings, but not "ready to brew", how do I fix this?

Here is my current path:

```
anian$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/anian/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
```

My current bash profile:

```
~/.bash_profile
-bash: /Users/anian/.bash_profile: Permission denied
```

I did this: echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
But I got nothing but what you see below, Please help.

This is what I got:

```
    anian$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config

Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so
    echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to reset my machine altogether, it doesn't appear there is a way to reset the path and make sure everything is stable at the same time.